Answer was deleted as "not an answer" even though I stress in the tested code that the temp tables have their data only in one of three main methods
My answer was deleted, see DFT drops connection and its temporary table after leaving any DFT item, tested with two Script Components. How do I keep the temp table alive?.
I gave the tested code, taking up the main hint of the other answer to release but not close the connection, but also showing a core trick on top, namely that the temporary tables are only filled with their data when entering the PostExecute() method.
Now that it got deleted, I made a remark under the accepted answer that makes this clear:

This is not yet the whole story. You get the filled temp tables back (tested in debug mode in SSMS) only in the PostExecute() method and unless you "SQL-touch" them, the temp table is not shown in SSMS. That was the main problem why I thought they would be dropped but they were not. They are not there in the PreExecute() method and they are empty 0-rows tables without data in the Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row). That is why I thought they would not stay alive.

The other remarks that said the same were also deleted, but I also put them into my answer later, so that if the answer was not deleted, the remarks would have survived. The remarks gave insight in what I needed to understand to answer the question in the code:

For someone who needs to fix the same thing, they add value, and it seems as if everything I answered and put as a remark was deleted to make a big clean up without any checks of what this question is about in its core.
I do not see why those remarks are not seen as helpful here since they mirror the work with the accepted answer.
What is more, I do not see why my deleted code example answer is not needed here. I give the fully tested code which just sets up what is in the accepted answer. What might not be clear to the reviewers is that much of the code is the default file that opens for a Script Component in SSIS, and that such a Script Component has the three core methods (among others) in this given order:

PreExecute()
Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
PostExecute()

The question:

DFT drops connection and its temporary table after leaving any DFT item, tested with two Script Components. How do I keep the temp table alive?

had an answer in that deleted answer since this deleted answer shows the code that - and how - you have to work in the PostExecute() method. All of the screenshots just show how the accepted answer is put to work. It is a proof by example code and settings screenshots.
I do also make further and longer remarks in the end that having the temp tables only in the PostExecute() is bad news, which it is, since you cannot pass the temp table to the output arrow from that method.
I can cut down the code answer so that there are less remarks and defaults in the code, but I do not see why it should not be an answer.
For those who judge on this: you need to understand that this is taking up the default SSIS Script Component file two times for the two Script Components in the example. This is not just randomly picked code from my workspace.
I answered twice which might have led to misunderstandings
What is more, I got the remark that "these answers" aren`t answers. I know that the other answer which also was deleted was not an answer, but I also tell this right at the beginning of it.

Not an answer to the question
This answer is far-fetched and is clearly not the answer since there is already a working answer. This is left for the searchwords since I first thought that this question could be linked to a connection manager that is not aligned between Control Flow and DFT.

This was my guessed answer in the first place when there was no other answer at all, therefore I also see a misunderstanding here if the remark says:

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

This was never about the accepted answer since there was no answer, so I do not see why you would write "To critique or request clarification from an author".
And although I would not want it to be deleted, since it itself is an unclear point to me, I am not discussing its deletion here.
But the other answer is an answer that is not at all on that same level, the two deleted answers have nothing to do with each other, that is why I answered twice at all.
Aim of this meta discussion
I want to ask the community to undelete the answer with the code example since it proves the accepted answer and stresses on top that you can deal with the temp table of Script Component 1 - once that you left it for Script Component 2 - only in the PostExecute() (btw.: I could have done all in Component 1 but that is not SSIS-like for the reader if all steps are done in one item, and I also just wanted to give it a try).
Without this, the question is not fully answered, and the accepted answer does not tell this. How should I go on to save this tested code example with the screenshots of the core settings for the community?

There were multiple flags on your answers, plus a system flag on the accepted answer due to the excessive number (24) of comments.
Both answers were long and tricky to evaluate, especially after reading through nearly 30 comments (and now a long meta question, too).
We do generally allow the question asker a bit more latitude as to what constitutes an answer. Showing how you adapted the accepted answer to your particular circumstances is one of the valid cases, in general.
Still, that wasn't clearly the case at the time I handled those flags. There was heaps of text to read, and the crucial part is not the most grammatical English:

Here is the full setup and code which takes up the other answer.

Nevertheless, I have undeleted that answer now.
In future, please try to leave fewer comments unnecessarily, and prefer to ask a new question (even if it needs to be self-answered) if you have related points to make or 'useful tips' to share. You are welcome to add your own answer as described above, but you may want to use clearer language so confusion doesn't arise.
This is a Question and Answer site after all, not Reddit.

Understood and thanks. It was a mess of remarks in there also for the other answerer to read since I had crunched on this problem for many days (it would be too emberassing to say how many). I had debugged so many things from the net and still could not find just one working way to add a new column with SQL to a temp table - all done in DFT. The Q/A was only the tip of the iceberg. There seems to be no hint on the net that temp tables can only be dealt with in the PostExcecute() method of the Script Component. All in all, the long story here was already founded on far too much working time.

Welcome to the DBA.SE and DBA.META.SE community.
DBA.SE isn't a typical threads community where answers are sometimes spread out over multiple sub-threads and where answers get discussed into oblivion. DBA.SE isn't even like the typical discussion forum, where threads go on for ever and ever and ... (ad nauseam).
Here at DBA.SE we like to keep things to the point, because we are a Q & A site. A person will ask a question and other people will try to answer the question to the best of their knowledge.
In the end the community will decide which answers are valuable (up- and down-voting) and the author will decide which answer was a solution to their question (accepted answer). In some cases the most up-voted answer might not even be the answer the author accepts.
You might want to have a look at the following articles from the help centre to better understand how the stackechange sites function.

Welcome to Database Administrators Stack Exchange
How do I ask a good question?
How do I write a good answer?

Thanks for your participation :-)

As you might not have seen: the answer that is "straight to the point" was not the full answer, it missed the second trick that the temp tables only have the data in the PostExecute() method, and I found out about this only after long hours. That is how all of my remarks came up. Thats is why I also do not agree with your way to see this Meta question. It is not about grace or education, but an answer must work to be an answer, and that is why I asked to reopen my code example answer. The other answer is still accepted since it helped me a lot to keep track and find out the next step.

You are allowed to disagree. That's one of the cool things about Stack Exchange.

I take Stack Exchange as a way to set down what I crunch on so that I can later look it up even if I switch companies. I can share the links for the internal docs and still have them public. SE is also about sharing anything that needs to be found out and does not catch your eye. What does not make it here is what is too easy, can be recalled or found quickly or is not worth saving.

No. SE is definitely not a blog. IMO.

I have not talked about a blog. It is about what I need for my work to be done and do not find here, and the voting to trace what helped me.
